# Spring DataJPA - preventing double form submission for One to One relationships

Tags: html, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf, crud, one-to-one

I am working on a simple Spring project which allows Restaurants to add dishes to a database using a Thymeleaf HTML form. Users can then search them based on a range of criteria.

I have also made it possible for Restaurants to add/ update their opening hours to the database- using the following methods in OpeningHoursServiceImp

**Save- Which allows the hours to be added initially**

```
@PostMapping("/saveOpeningHour")
public String saveOpeningHour(@ModelAttribute("openinghour")OpeningHour openinghour) {
        openingHourService.saveOpeningHourWithUserId(openinghour);  
        return "redirect:/dish";
        }
```

**Update- Which retrieves the opening hours to allows edits and re-save using the above save method**

```
        @GetMapping("/showOpeningForUpdate/{openingHourID}")
        public String showOpeningForUpdate(@PathVariable(value = "openingHourID") long openingHourID, Model model) {
            OpeningHour openingHour = openingHourService.getOpeningHourByOpeningHourID(openingHourID);
            model.addAttribute("openinghour", openingHour);
            return "opening_hours_update"
        }
```

These methods worked well when allowing restaurants to add dishes, as one restaurant can add many dishes (one to many relationship).

However the relationship between opening hours and restaurant is One to One so if the restaurant owner adds 2 sets of opening hours- the application crashes.

Is there a way to disable the add button once one set of opening hours have been submitted? Or handle the error properly in the save method?

[image: Screenshot of opening hours screen]

I have tried disabling 'save' within the "add opening hours form" using

```
onsubmit="myButton.disabled = true; return true;`
```

but it doesn't work (I assume because it is a web application and when the page is refreshed it becomes un-disabled?)

I'm new to Spring and finding it difficult. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Please see my html for viewing/editing/adding opening hours-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">


<head>

<title>Dish Management System</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
<body>
<br>
<br>
<br>
    
    <br>
    <div class="col-sm-10 offset-sm-1 text-center">
    <h1>Opening Hours</h1>
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WhatToEat</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/home">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        
        <form class = "form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" action="#" th:action="@{/logout}" method="POST">
        <button  class= "btn btn-outline-danger my-2 my-sm btn-sm" type= "submit"> logout </button> 
         </form>     
      </div>
     
    </nav>
    
    
    <table border="1" class="table table-striped table-responsive-md">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Opening Monday</th>
                <th>Opening Tuesday</th>
                <th>Opening Wednesday</th>
            </tr>


        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr th:each="openinghour : ${listopeninghours}">
                <td th:text="${openinghour.openingHourMon}"></td>
                <td th:text="${openinghour.openingHourTue}"></td>
                <td th:text="${openinghour.openingHourWed}"></td>
                
                <td><a th:href="@{/showOpeningForUpdate/{id}(id=${openinghour.openingHourID})}"
                    class="btn btn-primary">Update</a>
            </tr>
                         
        </tbody>
        
    </table>
    <div class="col-sm-10 offset-sm-1 text-center">
     <a th:href="@{/openinghour}"
        class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mb-3"  > Add Opening Hour </a>
        </div>
</body>
```

Please see my html form for adding/saving opening hours-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Opening Hours</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WhatToEat</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/home">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        
        <form class = "form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" action="#" th:action="@{/logout}" method="POST">
        <button  class= "btn btn-outline-danger my-2 my-sm btn-sm" type= "submit"> logout </button> 
         </form>     
      </div>
     
    </nav>
    <br>
    <br>

    <form action="#" th:action="@{/saveOpeningHour}" th:object="${openinghour}"  method="POST">
        <div class="col-sm-10 offset-sm-1 text-center">
        <div class="container">
            <br>
            
            <h2>Business Hours</h2>
            
                <hr>
            
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                    Closing Hours 
                    
                        <hr>
                    
                    
                    <input type="text" th:field="*{openingHourMon}"
                        placeholder="Monday" class="form-control mb-4 col-10">

                    <input type="text" th:field="*{openingHourTue}"
                        placeholder="Tuesday" class="form-control mb-4 col-10">

                    <input type="text" th:field="*{openingHourWed}"
                        placeholder="Wednesday" class="form-control mb-4 col-10">

                    <input type="text" th:field="*{openingHourThurs}"
                        placeholder="Thursday" class="form-control mb-4 col-10">

                    <input type="text" th:field="*{openingHourFri}"
                        placeholder="Friday" class="form-control mb-4 col-10">

                    <input type="text" th:field="*{openingHourSat}"
                        placeholder="Saturday" class="form-control mb-4 col-10">

                    <input type="text" th:field="*{openingHourSun}"
                        placeholder="Sunday" class="form-control mb-4 col-10">


                </div>

                <div class="col">
                Opening Hours
                    <hr>
                
                    
                     <input type="text" th:field="*{closingHourMon}"
                        placeholder="Monday" class="form-control mb-4 col-10">

                    <input type="text" th:field="*{closingHourTue}"
                        placeholder="Tuesday" class="form-control mb-4 col-10">

                    <input type="text" th:field="*{closingHourWed}"
                        placeholder="Wednesday" class="form-control mb-4 col-10">

                    <input type="text" th:field="*{closingHourThurs}"
                        placeholder="Thursday" class="form-control mb-4 col-10">

                    <input type="text" th:field="*{closingHourFri}"
                        placeholder="Friday" class="form-control mb-4 col-10">

                    <input type="text" th:field="*{closingHourSat}"
                        placeholder="Saturday" class="form-control mb-4 col-10">

                    <input type="text" th:field="*{closingHourSun}"
                        placeholder="Sunday" class="form-control mb-4 col-10">


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>



        <button type="submit" name ="myButton" class="btn btn-info col-4" >Save</button>
        <br>
        
        <a th:href="@{/open}"> Back to Opening Hours</a>
    </div>  
    </form>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When loading your page for managing opening hours, you can check if the list `listopeninghours` has an opening hour (which means `listopeninghours` is not null and the size of the list `listopeninghours` is not zero), then disable the button ***Add Opening Hour***.

The code will be something as follows.

```
<button th:disabled="${listopeninghours != null && #lists.size(listopeninghours) != 0}" onclick="goToOpeningHours()">Add Opening Hour</button>

<script>
    function goToOpeningHours(){
        window.location.href = /*[[ @{/openinghour} ]]*/ '';
    }
</script>
```

The `th:disabled` is responsible for disabling the button.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but  I think there's still something I'm not understanding. Where/how is the check for null value performed?
When I implemented the button above the button shows as disabled whether or not opening hour is null. 
Thanks again!

Comment: I have updated the answer based on the code snippets you provided in the question. Initially I thought you were using only one OpeningHour object to render the page. Then I saw your code and saw you are sending a list of opening hours.